# How to pass null from Kotlin code to a method taking String as argument in Java library?

Tags: kotlin

I am using microsoft auth (MSAL) SDK in my android app.The SDK is in Java but my app is in Kotlin. I need to pass String as null for the argument loginHint to signIn Java method.
Example in my Kotlin code:-

```
mSingleAccountApp?.signIn(this@MainActivity, null!!, getScopes(), getAuthInteractiveCallback())
```

I tried converting the code by pasting into android studio but it converted null to null!! which will give instant NPE.
Method signature in Java library:-

```
void signIn(@NonNull final Activity activity,
                @NonNull final String loginHint,
                @NonNull final String[] scopes,
                @NonNull final AuthenticationCallback callback);
```

Comment: _"I need to pass String as null for the argument loginHint to signIn Java method."_ Why is that a requirement?  Can you not just pass in an empty String, instead?

Comment: @Jordan The compiler wont allow to pass null as you are saying

Comment: Would you have passed a `null` in your java code? Would it have acted differently if you passed `null` in the java code?

Comment: I think you have explicitly specified the String argument to be notnull. So it will not allow you to pass empty string.

Comment: @thedu_girl can you show the stack trace you get when you get a NPE?

Comment: @Giora Guttsait you are supposed to add !! in the suffix of an object only when you are sure its not null. So directly adding !! to null is a suicide mission.

Comment: @thedu_girl I'm still not sure why you need to be able to pass a null to that method.  Can you not just pass in an empty String if there's no login hint?

Comment: I was referring to sample code(Java) and they are passing null. Moreover I want to know out of curiosity of such a situation where passing empty string is not an option.

Comment: @thedu_girl this is why I was asking about the stacktrace. I know Kotlin at times places non-null assertions at certain places, and it may be the case here. If we see the stack trace, we can identify where the NPE is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If the signature weren't marked with `@NonNull`, you could pass `null as String?` as a parameter to help the compiler find the right method overload.

But since it's marked `@NonNull`, the API of this library is saying it is not designed to accept a null parameter. [The Kotlin compiler respects many common Java nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations), so it prevents you from even compiling this.

Without looking at its docs, I'd guess you should just pass an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in the Java declaration: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/a7b4a07074aef16b1fe36192ae1997203b37b9b3/msal/src/main/java/com/microsoft/identity/client/ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.java#L66-L86

While `loginHint` is described as being optional, it is marked as `@NonNull` in the parameter list, so Kotlin respects this annotation and thinks `null` is not allowed here.

The best way to deal with it is to file an issue about the incorrect nullability to the library authors (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues), but to work around it for now you can declare a static helper function in java with the right nullability information:

```java
// here I'm using org.jetbrains.annotations to declare the right nullability:
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

// A java helper class
class SingleAccountPublicClientApplicationUtils {
    static void signIn(@NotNull final ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication application,
                       @NotNull final Activity activity,
                       @Nullable final String loginHint,
                       @NotNull final String[] scopes,
                       @NotNull final AuthenticationCallback callback) {
        // just call application.signIn, java doesn't care about nullability annotations
        application.signIn(activity, loginHint, scopes, callback);
    }
}
```